# linespacing and \large

Tags: line-spacing

When I run the following code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{2}
\def\lipsum{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing
vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a}
\begin{document}

{\Large
\lipsum

\lipsum
}

{\Large
\lipsum

\lipsum

}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, the linespacing of the second paragraph is different. What's wrong? I want to understand the reason so that I won't make a mistake in a similar context.

Comment: You always want to finish the current paragraph (empty line or `\par`) before switching back to another font. Otherwise the line spacing will be taken from the font active at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: Off-topic: The `article` document class does not recognize `9pt` as a valid option -- and thus simply ignores it.

Comment: Does anybody know a good duplicate target for this?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I picked one (there are loads to choose from:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Too many possible dupes was my problem, I checked about 10, but they were all a mixture of different problems. Yours is much better than the ones I found!